# Unity Post Processing looks different between Scene and Game view

Tags: unity-game-engine, post-processing

Hey I'm making a little game but I have a big problem because:
As you can see the difference between picture 1 and picture 2 you can see today's problem,
I have no idea why the two are different. because the 3D view looks the same on both, but for some reason my 2D menu UI (the scene view) looks better than my game view. Still have no idea why
Thanks in Advance

[image: Image 1 & 2]

Comment: Do you have multiple Cameras? Looks like one isn't rendered in the Game view or maybe not all layers are selected for being rendered correctly

Comment: unfortunatly there is no second camera in this scene, this problem as i told only appears in the UI so i dont know why, because if i turn off the "Post Processing" in the scene view it looks identical with the game. But it seems that the Post Processing dont affect the UI in Game View. I hope i did not overscoped this comment.

Comment: which graphics API are you using? DirectX, OpenGL, Metal, Vulkan?

Comment: @nka_Zz i dont know the exact one, but there is the auto windows api checked

Comment: then prolly DX on windows, Metal on apple and OpenGL under Linux. Since you solved it is fine. It was more than unlikely that it has anything to do with [this](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/texture-color-changes-when-enabling-post-processing-on-camera-with-opengl) anyways, since your color shift is to major. But OpenGL has a little bit of color tint when activating post processing under URP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Its fixed,** but for those people who accomplish this in the future:
I changed the Canvas Space from [*Screen Space - Overlay*] to [*Screen Space - Camera*].
but i cant explain exactly why its the solution.

Comment: That should be expected since Screen Space Overlay renders the UI directly on top of the Screen, while Screen Space Camera puts the UI at a certain distance. So in the first case  the glowing light from the background will be disregarded while on the second  case it can affect the camera depending on the camera settings. You can read more about it on the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UICanvas.html)